# GET ALL RECORDS AFTER LOAD STORE

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store

i'm having a little issue with Extjs 4.2.1. When i trying to RELOAD the grid using params. I do this... in a button click action...

```
var oForm = Ext.create('GlcAccounting.view.frmPyLMonth');

oForm.query('textfield[id="txtPylNumber"]')[0].setValue(pPylNumber);

var oGrid = oForm.query('grid[id="grdPylDetail"]')[0];

oGrid.getStore().load({
    params: {
        Num_pyl: pPylNumber
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    console.log(records);
}
});


if (oForm.isVisible())
    oForm.hide();
else
    oForm.show();
```

So, althought i have so much records(more than 100 in my store)... my grid only shows 1 record. Do i need to call any other method? What could be happening?

Thank you in advance....

Comment: you are providing wrong information. It would be helpful to see how the grid is defined, and store is associated to it. My advice is to simplify your code, create a basic grid associate it with a store. and load the store. watch it work properly and then slowly add your changes.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in sencha fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, in Extjs, when you are loading multiple records and you only get one, it is because of the primary key of the records (by default "id") being the same (including being defined and empty or null) for all of them.

Comment: Yes you were right, the problem was i was set my idproperty to one field(id), but in that table, its primary key is a combined field. So i do a trick to get working. Thank you in adavance.